# Cassandra and R via JDBC: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.Utils

Tags: java, r, jdbc, cassandra, cassandra-jdbc

I am trying to access Cassandra with R via JDBC.
Unfortunately, even if I have the jar package `cassandra-jdbc-1.2.5.jar` correctly
installed in `/usr/share/cassandra/lib/`, containing the file `org/apache/cassandra/cql/jdbc/Utils.class`, I get the following error:

```
> library(RJDBC)
Loading required package: DBI
Loading required package: rJava
> cassdrv <- JDBC("org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver",
+ list.files("/usr/share/cassandra/lib/",pattern="jar$",full.names=T))
>  #Connect to Cassandra node and Keyspace
> casscon <- dbConnect(cassdrv, "jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9160/something")
Error in .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect", as.character(url)[1],  : 
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.Utils
```

(Using cassandra 2.1.2, cassandra JDBC 1.2.5, R 3.1.2, CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406)

Any idea on why this happens?

Also, I opened this bug report: https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-jdbc/issues/detail?id=100

Answer (score 0):

If there's a mismatch between the rJava version of java and the version used to compile the Cassandra jars, they may not actually be included in the classpath even if they're reported by `.jclassPath()`.